# Filename root not correctly extracted

Tags: bash, shell

I would like to extract the filename (root) from a file with specific extension (.datt). This file is the only single file in my directory but could change its root name but extension remains fixed; therefore I need to use a "wildcard" to capture the name. Here is my little script that incorrectly outputs all the files. Appreciate your help.

```
# Target file in the folder >> test.datt
myfile=*.datt
echo $myfile
echo
root="${myfile%.datt}"
echo $root
```

My output

```
test.datt

temp test.datt testroot
```

Expected output

```
test
```

Comment: You might try using `find` with a combination of bash parameter expansions.  Something like `f=$(find . -name '*.datt') ; f="${f##*/}" ; echo "${f%%.*}"`

Comment: @j_b: thanks. this script worked.

Comment: You might also want to consider using [basename](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/basename.1.html).

Comment: See [I just assigned a variable, but echo $variable shows something else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else). Your first echo is tricking you into believing that `myfile` contains `test.datt` but it really contains `*.datt`, then when you remove the extension you just get `*` which expands to all files in the directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean code:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

myfiles=( *.datt )
echo "${myfiles[0]}"
echo
root=${myfiles[0]%.datt}
echo "$root"
```

- The output in the question occurs because `echo $myfile` is equivalent to `echo *.datt`, `$root` has the value (literal) `*`, and `echo $root` is equivalent to `echo *`.
- With `myfiles=( *.datt )` the array `myfiles` is populated with the list of files that match `*.datt` (expected to be exactly one).
- See [BashGuide/Arrays - Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays) for good information about Bash arrays.